# Trying to figure out this ruby snippet of code described as a recursice search

Tags: ruby, recursion

The code snippet is part of a cut sheet algorithm that I'm trying to improve on and modify.

Here's the code with notes left from the previous coder. I'm trying to figure out how the code finds the 'best fit'. I was expecting some sort of array comparison of results but I've never come across recursive search as it's described and don't understand how a result is achieved and, how I could improve on the results:

```
# use a recursive search to find the best spot for a part
# best fit means least wastage ie: the area of the piece to place comes closes to the area of the space
# from the given Node, return a result if it is a leaf node, otherwise go left, then go right recursively.
# returns the chosen best leaf node


def findBestFit(node, part_length, part_width)
    return nil      if node==nil    # nothing here if this is a nil node
    # am i in a node or a leaf
    leaf=false
    leaf=true       if node.getNodeType=="leaf"

    if leaf # look at the leaf if we are a leaf
        # won't fit if length is too short
        # Note: make the comparisons here after applying the length transformation.
        # This gives the same level of accuracy as the model units - which is what is relevant for layout
        # Otherwise, there may be inaccurate comparisons between internal numbers which have been
        # subjected to scaling, multiplication etc which can make round numbers into floats thus preventing
        # parts from fitting when by all practical measures, they do.

        return nil  if part_length.to_l > node.rect[:length].to_l               # won't fit if length is too narrow
        return nil  if part_width.to_l > node.rect[:width].to_l                 # won't fit if width is too narrow
        return node                                                             # fits, so return as a potential best fit
    end

    # it's a node
    bestLeft=findBestFit(node.left, part_length, part_width)    #go left
    bestRight=findBestFit(node.right, part_length, part_width)  #go right

    return nil          if bestLeft==nil && bestRight==nil  # now determine which is the best. No brainer if one or both are nil
    return bestLeft     if bestRight== nil
    return bestRight    if bestLeft==nil

    # otherwise both are potentials and we have to choose one
    # pick based on best fit  ie: least amount of waste left or the one further to the origin of the board or both. User can select
    # the bias, otherwise we use both rules and try to pack the parts from left to right
    # (note area on the board must >= the part size because of earlier decisions)

    part_area=part_length*part_width
    ruleA=(((bestLeft.rect[:length]*bestLeft.rect[:width])-part_area)<=((bestRight.rect[:length]*bestRight.rect[:width])-part_area)) && @layoutOptions[:layoutRuleA]
    ruleB=(bestLeft.rect[:xy][0]<bestRight.rect[:xy][0]) && @layoutOptions[:layoutRuleB]

    return bestLeft     if ruleA || ruleB
    return bestRight
end
```

Comment: If it's any comfort, this code is procedural and awful.

For example, the expression "part_length.to_l > node.rect[:length].to_l " could be a method #is_too_long, and many of the other expressions could similarly be methods in their own right. The entire findBestFit method ought to be a class, and "findBestFit(node.left, part_length, part_width)" ought instead to be "BestFit.new(node: node.left, part: part).call". The good news is that you have an excellent learning opportunity in which you turn this procedural mess into properly object-oriented code: http://www.poodr.com

Comment: to compound on what @DavidAldridge said the early returns (other than the initial one `return nil if node==nil` which would be better as `return node unless node`) are awful as well. This should be extrapolated into a class to handle the logic and would offer a much cleaner interface and more logical understanding of the process. BTW who wrote this because it does not seem to follow even the basics of ruby convention including `snake_case` naming.

Comment: Glad the code isn't that easy to understand... I'm usually pretty good at figuring out what code does but this has got me baffled to say the least! The code is part of a sketchup plugin found here https://extensions.sketchup.com/en/content/cutlist From my understanding the guy who originally wrote the code just gave up updating it and the guy who took over has passed away. I wanted to create a cut sheet plugin from scratch but figured since most of the leg work has already been done I could work with it but damn I'm having a hard time figuring out the code!

Comment: Do you have tests for it? Could you write some? It's a lot easier to refactor complex code when you can run tests after each code modification.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes I'm able to test changes through sketchup but this part of the code I just can't figure out how it comes to the conclusion of a 'best fit'.